# Failed to change logFile directory in configuration file

Tags: dolphindb

Reference: [DolphinDB user manual](https://dolphindb.com/help/DatabaseandDistributedComputing/Configuration/StandaloneMode.html).

I have set up a cluster. I configured the *logFile* configuration parameter in the file `controller.cfg` to specify the log file directory. Then I started the server with the `startController.sh` script and the log is still saved under the same directory as the script. My earlier configuration doesn’t take effect. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*logFile* can only be specified in command line.

To change log directory, you can specify the configuration parameter when starting the node. The script *startController.sh* defaults the `-logFile` directory to the same directory as the script itself.

Therefore, if you want to modify the directory of the log, modify the directory after `logFile` in the command line.